# Nagiographer on Debian Wheezy work partialy

Tags: debian, nagios

I made standard installation which is Nagios3 + Nagiosgrapher on Debian 7.6.  In `/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg` I added:

```
process_performance_data=1 and service_perfdata_command=ngraph-process-service-perfdata-pipe
```

Restarted Nagios.  In the web interface I see that nagiosgrapher made a graph for localhost HTTP, which is great.

I added to `/etc/nagios3/conf.d/services_nagios2.cfg`:

```
define service {
    name nagiosgraph
    action_url /cgi-bin/nagios3/graphs.cgi?host=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$'
    register 0
}
```

Like always this shows a graph-a-like icon, and when clicked I get new window with graph which is not populated.

I see that `/etc/nagiosgrapher/nagios3/serviceext` isn't populating automatically.

`/var/log/nagiosgrapher/ngraph.log` doesn't show any anomaly.

I'm probably using some old witchcraft method to add graph.  But how to add them now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were almost none ncfg files inside /etc/nagiosgrapher/ngraph.d/standard and extra
I download the tar.gz from author page, untar it, copy few files, and it started to working

Answer (score 0):

Using the Debian packages, the only thing you need to do manually is add these 2 lines to the main Nagios config file:

```
process_performance_data=1
service_perfdata_command=ngraph-process-service-perfdata-pipe
```

This is documented in `/usr/share/doc/nagiosgrapher/README.Debian`

Make sure there's a symlink from `/etc/nagios3/conf.d/ngraph` to `/etc/nagiosgrapher/nagios3`. The package sets this up, but you might have lost it somehow.

Once the files in `/etc/nagiosgrapher/nagios3/serviceext` are auto-generated, you have to *reload* nagios3 for it to pick them up.

(Side note: Nagiosgrapher is kind of terrible. You might want to consider `pnp4nagios` instead. It's packaged, too.)

Comment: what should I add to make graphs for all of my services? or they are added by default ?

Comment: it comes with a bunch of graph templates, but you need to write your own for "non-standard" checks. see the files in /etc/nagiosgrapher/ngraph.d/standard/ for examples